# Loading data into a datagridviewcomboboxcolumn

Tags: vb.net, datagridviewcombobox

I have a `datagridviewcomboxcolumn` to which I need to load data either from another form or by excel.
Before loading, I am validating the data to make sure it exists in the datagridviewcomboxcolumn list.
Whenever I try to load the data, it gives an exception error as value is not valid.

How can this be solved? 
Or
is there a workaround to disable this error?

Comment: What does your code look like where the problem is occuring.

Comment: Check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) MSDN article